# Managing the various pieces of javascript in an angular application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been writing a small angular front-end application to consume my REST API.

The issue I am having now, is that I have actually separated the various HTML pages in order to pull them in to the ng-view when needed in my single page application.

My question is, do I need to separate the javascript that is specific to certain pages, out to separate javascript files - and then have each javascript file that needs that code, import it? Or do I just put it all in the one big JS file?

Just trying to work out the best way to do this, I assume either would work, but which is right?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this Google Doc for structuring Angular apps
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub

Answer (score 0):

If application is small, then you can create few javascript files and have  for each of them in your index.html file.

If your application is big, then look into using grunt or gulp. I would recommend gulp over grunt, but it just me.

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in one file.

You can use the same JS file for every HTML page. Just make sure to use unique ID's for every HTML page elements you want to manipulate.